# jQuery and preventing function from executing twice when hyperlink double-clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple HTML page with a hyperlink. The link works perfectly and executes a jQuery function. I will an alert saying "Now".

The problem is that when a user double clicks the link, it will execute the jQuery code twice and diplays "Now" alert twice. When I next time click the link only once, it will execute the jQuery code twice or even more times and I will get several "Now" alerts.

How should I modify my code to prevent the jQuery code from being executed more than one time?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="editing" data-match="1" data-place="1" data-selected="20" data-checking="area">Use</a>
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.editing', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
      match = $this.data('match'),
      place = $this.data('place'),
      selected = $this.data('selected'),
      checking = $this.data('checking');

  jQuery.post("myownpage.php", {
    match: match,
    place: place,
    selected: selected,
    checking: checking
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert('Now');
    $('html').css({ 'overflow': 'auto', 'height': 'auto' });
    $this.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

Comment: You could use `.one` and then rebind your click after the post has completed

Comment: do you want the link to be clickable just once per each page load ?

Comment: @AlaaMh Yes, I guess so.

Comment: you could handle it using css by adding `pointer-events: none;` after clicking the link, this will prevent the link to be clickable or you can either hide the link after the first click by adding `display: none;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a external scoped variable ( here eventComplete) to understand whether the event is complete or not

```
var eventComplete = true;
 jQuery(document).on('click', '.editing', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if( eventComplete ) {
      eventComplete = false;
      var $this = $(this),
        match = $this.data('match'),
        place = $this.data('place'),
        selected = $this.data('selected'),
        checking = $this.data('checking');

      jQuery.post("myownpage.php", {
        match: match,
        place: place,
        selected: selected,
        checking: checking
      }).done(function(data) {
        alert('Now');
        $('html').css({ 'overflow': 'auto', 'height': 'auto' });
  $this.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
       eventComplete = true;
     });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`jQuery.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), it executes event handlers only once. Like so -

`$(document).one('click', eventHandler)`

The other way round is to rewrite the handler reference to an empty handler after doing its work, like so -

```
var eventHandler = function(e) {

// point eventHandler to a do nothing function
eventHandler = function(){ return false;};

e.preventDefault();

var $this = $(this),
    match = $this.data('match'),
    place = $this.data('place'),
    selected = $this.data('selected'),
    checking = $this.data('checking');

jQuery.post("myownpage.php", {
  match: match,
  place: place,
  selected: selected,
  checking: checking
}).done(function(data) {
  alert('Now');
  $('html').css({ 'overflow': 'auto', 'height': 'auto' });
  $this.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
});
};

jQuery(document).on('click', '.editing', eventHandler);
```

Or you can use the `off` method to remove the listener, instead of reassigning the reference to the do-nothing function.

Comment: It seems to me that `e.preventDefault();` does not work anymore.

Comment: Updated with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Check with some `increment` .if you click one time `c=1` next time `c=2` if condition was not allowe above `1`

```
var c=0;
jQuery(document).on('click', '.editing', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  c ++;
if(c > 1)
{
  var $this = $(this),
      match = $this.data('match'),
      place = $this.data('place'),
      selected = $this.data('selected'),
      checking = $this.data('checking');

  jQuery.post("myownpage.php", {
    match: match,
    place: place,
    selected: selected,
    checking: checking
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert('Now');
    $('html').css({ 'overflow': 'auto', 'height': 'auto' });
    $this.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
  });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind multiple `event` in same function. You can set same function `dblclick` so it will run once..

```
jQuery(document).on('click dblclick', '.editing', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
      match = $this.data('match'),
      place = $this.data('place'),
      selected = $this.data('selected'),
      checking = $this.data('checking');

  jQuery.post("myownpage.php", {
    match: match,
    place: place,
    selected: selected,
    checking: checking
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert('Now');
    $('html').css({ 'overflow': 'auto', 'height': 'auto' });
    $this.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example.
It outputs Single clicks and double clicks separately.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="div">My Div</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var flag = false;
var time;

$(document).on("dblclick", ".div", function(e) {
    flag = true;
    alert("Double Clicked");
 });

 $(".div").on("click",function(e) {

    time = setTimeout(function(){
        var x =checkSingleClick();
        console.log(x);
        if(x){
            alert("Single Clicked"); 
        }else{
            flag = false;  
        }  
    clearTimeout(time);        
    },350);

 });

 function checkSingleClick(){
        if(flag == false){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
 }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```